# why android ACTION_UUID returns wrong object

Tags: android, python, bluetooth

I'm trying to write a python bluetooth library for android using kivy's python for android. I import java classes using autoclass from jnius module. It is working good so far, however, when I call the function fetchUuidsWithSdp() and check the ACTION_UUID intent for the fetched uuid's I get a wrong object. The code I'm using is:

```
elif action == ACTION_UUID:
    print("....... ACTION_UUID .......")
    extras = intent.getExtras()
    fetchedUUIDs = extras.get(EXTRA_UUID)
    # fetchedUUIDs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(EXTRA_UUID)
    print("fetchedUUIDs object type is: ..............")
    print (fetchedUUIDs)
    for u in fetchedUUIDs:
        print u.toString()
```

so I get in the adb console the following print out:

```
I/python  (30971): ....... ACTION_UUID .......
I/python  (30971): fetchedUUIDs object type is: ..............
I/python  (30971): [<android.os.Parcelable at 0x7c1f2600 jclass=android/os/Parcelable jself=<LocalRef obj=0x20f00dfa at 0x79f7bab0>>,     <android.os.Parcelable at 0x7c1
```

which shows the object type of 'fetchedUUIDs' is 'android.os.Parcelable' list insteed of 'ParcelUuid' list. When I call toString() I get the following trace:

```
I/python  (30971):  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  (30971):    File "jnius/jnius_proxy.pxi", line 47, in jnius.jnius.PythonJavaClass.invoke (jnius/jnius.c:24931)
I/python  (30971):    File "jnius/jnius_proxy.pxi", line 73, in jnius.jnius.PythonJavaClass._invoke (jnius/jnius.c:25609)
I/python  (30971):    File "/home/tito/code/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/android/broadcast.py", line 18, in onReceive
I/python  (30971):    File "main.py", line 235, in on_broadcast
I/python  (30971):      print u.toString()
I/python  (30971):  AttributeError: 'android.os.Parcelable' object has no attribute 'toString'
```

Is there any thing wrong in my code? any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Glen for your help. The code I used is what android sdk explains.

I have finally managed to get the services UUID's using the device object which is passed also in the intent extras as follows:

```
elif action == ACTION_UUID:
    print("....... ACTION_UUID .......")
    extras = intent.getExtras()
    fetchedDevice = extras.get(EXTRA_DEVICE)
    fetchedUUIDs = fetchedDevice.getUuids()
    if fetchedUUIDs:
        for u in fetchedUUIDs:
            print u.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are either not creating a UUID upstream in your java code or it is not being passed into your Intent extras like you're expecting it to.

Are you sure that fetchUuidsWithSdp() is returning a UUID in your java code? Are you sure that the UUID is being passed correctly through the Intent in your java code?

It would be helpful to see the code you're using to generate and transmit the original UUID that appears to be missing.